# non-English friendly MVC web framework

Tags: model-view-controller, web-frameworks, non-english

I've tried several MVC web development frameworks (like Ruby on Rails and cakePHP), and they are great.

However, because of their "convention over configuration" philosophy, they seem to be not very well suited for non-English projects, most notably because of **forcing English plural in object-relational mapping and URLs**.

What do developers that need/want their database tables and URLs to be in non-English usually do? Is there a framework that is really good with this, or do they tweak/hack routing and ORM? If so, which frameworks make this configurations most convinient?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails allows you to define rules for creating plurals in mappings and URLs. Just look for information on ***inflections.rb*** in Rails for your native language and you might find somebody already figured out the proper ones.